# Matlab GUI: waiting for value update before KeyPressFcn call

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm writing a GUI in Matlab, which among other functionalities should allow you to write a text in an `edit`-`uicontrol`, and then add that text to a list when pressing the enter key.

I am using the `KeyPressFcn` method for the edit box to test whether enter is pressed, and my problem is that it does not update the `String` value of the `edit` `uicontrol`, so the string added to the list is not actually the one I just entered, but a previous incarnation of the string in the `edit`.

Now I have already searched for solutions to this problem and found a [solution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/26036-how-to-update-editbox-uicontrol-string-during-keypressfcn), but I would very much prefer a solution strictly contained in Matlab - that is not referring to java.

Is this is possible? And if it is, how?

A minimal working example:

```
function [fig] = tmpGUI()
    fig = figure('MenuBar','none');
    handles.fig = fig;
    handles.edit = uicontrol(fig,'Style','edit','Units','Normalized','Position',[.05,.75,.9,.2],'Backgroundcolor','white','String','','KeyPressFcn',@edit_KeyPressFcn);
    handles.list = uicontrol(fig,'Style','listbox','Units','Normalized','Position',[.05,.05,.9,.65],'Backgroundcolor','white','String','First element in list');
    guidata(fig,handles);
    uicontrol(handles.edit);
end

function edit_KeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata)
    handles = guidata(hObject);
    switch eventdata.Key
        case 'return'
            str = get(handles.edit,'String');
            liste = cellstr(get(handles.list,'String'));
            liste{end+1} = str;
            set(handles.list,'String',char(liste),'Value',numel(liste));
    end
end
```

Edit: I'm running Matlab R2014a.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `callback` property of the `edit` uicontrol will be triggered when you press `enter`, so it would be easier to use this callback instead of the `KeyPressFcn`.

Just when you enter the callback, check that the last character pressed was `enter`. If yes update your list, if not just do nothing and go on.

This example seems to do what you asked. Let me know if they are other conditions to be checked.

```
function [fig] = tmpGUI()
    fig = figure('MenuBar','none');
    handles.fig = fig;
    handles.edit = uicontrol(fig,'Style','edit','Units','Normalized','Position',[.05,.75,.9,.2],'Backgroundcolor','white','String','','Callback',@edit_callback);
    handles.list = uicontrol(fig,'Style','listbox','Units','Normalized','Position',[.05,.05,.9,.65],'Backgroundcolor','white','String','First element in list');
    guidata(fig,handles);
    uicontrol(handles.edit);
end

function edit_callback(hObject, evt)
    handles = guidata(hObject);
    %// just check if the last key pressed was "enter"
    %// if yes, update the list 
    if double(get(gcf,'currentcharacter'))==13
        str = get(handles.edit,'String');
        liste = cellstr(get(handles.list,'String'));
        liste{end+1} = str;
        set(handles.list,'String',char(liste),'Value',numel(liste));
    end
    %// if not, the callback has been trigerred by a click somewhere else
    %// this is not a validation condition to update the list so we just
    %// do ... nothing
end
```

---

Edit: To add more information, the Matlab edit uicontrol are not updated internally before they are validated. The value in the edit will only be validated by (i) The `enter` key is pressed, or (ii) the txtbox looses focus (user click somewhere else).

In your initial case you are intercepting the `enter` key and executing code, but because you intercepted the `enter` key, the textbox didn't validate yet and in its internal memory it still have the old value, so your interception code capture the old value. Remembering a older question I answered relating to these textbox, there is not Matlab way of forcing the textbox to validate its content programmatically without using some java tricks.

So in your case (you want to react to the `enter` key), it is possible in pure Matlab thanks to the callback mechanics. If you want to execute some code when reacting to **any other key**, then you will have to force the textbox validation programmatically which can only be done by calling java methods (actually the link you mentioned in your original post is quite neat, the way I found before was quite more convoluted).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is that the keypressfunction is called every time you enter a single character. Use a `Callback` instead:

```
function [fig] = tmpGUI()
    fig = figure('MenuBar','none');
    handles.fig = fig;
    handles.edit = uicontrol(fig,'Style','edit','Units','Normalized','Position',[.05,.75,.8,.2],'Backgroundcolor','white','String','', 'Callback',@edit_KeyPressFcn);
    handles.list = uicontrol(fig,'Style','listbox','Units','Normalized','Position',[.05,.05,.9,.65],'Backgroundcolor','white','String','First element in list');

    guidata(fig,handles);
    uicontrol(handles.edit);
end

function edit_KeyPressFcn(hObject, eventdata)

    handles = guidata(hObject);
    str = get(handles.edit,'String');

    % ignore empty strings
    if isempty(str)
        return;
    end

    liste = cellstr(get(handles.list,'String'));
    liste{end+1} = str;
    set(handles.list,'String',char(liste),'Value',numel(liste));

end
```

Comment: I already have such a button in my GUI - I want to add the other functionality for the sake of efficiency; I'll probably be using the GUI a lot, and I don't want to bother using the mouse, when a simple key press should be able to handle my problem.

Comment: @JensBoldsen so you want to only enter single characters and add them one by one and line by line to the list?

Comment: No, I only want to at the text when the enter key is pressed - that is why I in my example test whether `eventdata.Key` is equal to `return`.

Comment: @JensBoldsen see my updated answer. It implements what you want.